# Layout neutrality of the <span> tag

Tags: layout, html

I'm considering the use of the `<span>` tag for grouping a set of arbitrary elements together, but I don't want it to have any visual impact in the structure of the document whatsoever.

I want to use that tag for later manipulating the set of elements within it with JavaScript in some way, such as e.g. detecting whether the mouse entered or left the region, etc.

My question is whether there are cases when the presence of the span tag will disrupt the flow of the document, making the elements within it or the elements around it behave differently from when it's absent.

Of course, I'm aware the presence of an additional node on the DOM can disrupt some CSS selectors which are not expecting the span, and I'm also aware that styling the span can cause the layout to change (e.g. if I added a border I could cause elements to wrap to the next line, etc.). But aside from that, is the span tag neutral? If not, how should I go about figuring in what cases it is not?

Thanks in advance!

-- edit --

I tend to forget that it's wrong to put block-level elements inside inline elements like span, so I can't use span to wrap just everything the way I intended.

So, in case one or more of the elements I'm grouping is block-level, should I use a div instead?

Comment: I tried wrapping block elements with spans to see if there was visual change and saw no change, but I might just have been lucky (or should I say unlucky?). So I wanted to ask to be sure if it's layout-neutral by definition or that was just my impression.

Comment: Can we see the code plz?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't really write code, I used the web inspector to add span tags around stuff here in StackOverflow, such as the ads to the right. I'm not as interested in the practical cases as much as I'm interested to the standards definition of the span element. I should have taken a look at the official document before posting; I'll do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<span>` element is defined to be an inline (text-level) element. Otherwise, it is semantically empty and layout-neutral.

By HTML syntax, the `<span>` element must not contain block elements, such as `<div>`. If you violate this, there is no specification of what browsers should no. It sounds pointless to play with that, when you can use the `<div>` element. It is defined to be a block element, which means that in rendering it by default starts on a new line and any content after it starts on a new line (but no empty lines are generated by this behavior). Otherwise, it is semantically empty and layout-neutral.

Comment: The "trophy" is yours (: I came to that same conclusion after some deliberation. I'll get back to this question and update it if I find out a case where neither divs nor spans can be used in a layout-neutral way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Directly of http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/span

> The  element doesn't mean anything on its own, but can be useful when used together with the global attributes, e.g. class, lang, or dir. It represents its children.

Comment: I saw that, but turns out it's wrong to wrap block-level elements with it. I think when block-level elements are among the children, the right thing to do is to use a div.

Comment: Well, depending on what you want to do from start. And reading your question a `<div>` that is a block isn't the way to go if you don't want to break up the text that wraps the `<div>`. It will break any line it's inserted into, if you don't float it, or set it as (that's right) a `display:inline-block`. And by then it removes it purpose all together. But if you DO want an element that comes out of the box as a block, do use the `<div>` since it is also a "meaningless" tag like `<span>`.

Comment: Also, w3c says "Generally, inline elements may contain only data and other inline elements." (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#block-inline). So they don't say that you can not use it.